# Need recommendation on control structure for simple led program

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

Assignment requires 4 int input to select different mode of LED blinking

1. On
2. Off
3. Blinking
4. Reduced duty cycle

Would apperciate advice on a better implementation of control structure.

Current implmentation

```
int main() 
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode (23, OUTPUT) ;
    pinMode (26, OUTPUT) ;
    
    int select; 
    printf("\nKey in number: ");
    scanf("%d", &select);
    if (select == 1)
    {
        turnOn();
        main();
    } 
    else if (select == 0)
    {
        turnOff();
        main();
    }
    else if (select == 2)
    {
        blinking();
        main();
    }
    else if (select == 3)
    {
        pattern();
        main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could consider using `switch(select)` instead of a chain of `if ... else`. And move the *very unwise* recursive call of `main()` to follow afterwards. It is common to all, so does not need to be repeated.

Comment: And a loop instead of purely needless recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling main everytime is unnecessary if you want to loop back you can just use a while(true) it will stay there forever(you can change this by putting a condition). And using a chain of if else looks bad. Switch case is much better (its faster).

```
int main() {
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode (23, OUTPUT) ;
    pinMode (26, OUTPUT) ;
    
    while(true) {
        int select; 
        printf("\nKey in number: ");
        scanf("%d", &select);

        switch(select) {
            case 0:
                turnOff();
                break;
            case 1:
                turnOn();
                break;
            case 2:
                blinking();
                break;
            case 3:
                pattern();
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
void (* const mode[])(void) =
{
    turnOff, turnOn, blinking, pattern
};

for (;;)
{
    unsigned int select;
    printf("\nKey in number: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if ((scanf("%u", &select) == 1) &&
        (select < sizeof(mode)/sizeof(*mode)))
    {
        mode[select]();
    }
}
```